# XPath to target first ancestor tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Some HTML:

```html
<div>
  
  <div>
    <button>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="x" />
      </svg>
    </button>    
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button>                                      <!-- I want this -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="y" />                            <!-- I have this -->
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I have the data (`y`) to target the second `path`, and then I want to get its ancestor `button`.

I can target the `path` element like this:

```xml
//svg/path[@d='y']
```

But I can't target its closest ancestor `button`:

```xml
//svg/path[@d='y']/ancestor::button
```

A demo [is here](http://xpather.com/JkRz6yxv).

And if I try this in firefox or chromium devtools (for the page containing the above markup):

```
$x("//ancestor::button[1]", document.querySelector("path[d='y']"))
```

...it returns many results, not just the first ancestor button.

Comment: Your last XPath is working fine with `xidel`

Comment: @GillesQuénot Thanks. So I suppose that online tester "xpather.com" is faulty.

Comment: https://github.com/benibela/xidel command line tool. I don't see how to trigger the XPath on the link

Comment: Are you aware that your documents has some HTML elements in no namespace but some SVG in the SVG namespace? How are you parsing the input, as HTML, as XML, with namespace support or without? That all is important to know to judge whether e.g. `//svg` selects that SVG `svg` element or nothing. As for your `$x("//ancestor::button[1]", document.querySelector("path[d='y']"))` attempt, that should be `$x("ancestor::button[1]", document.querySelector("path[d='y']"))`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. It's an HTML document, being parsed in the browser. BTW, your code snippet worked for me in the browser, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the browser, and with the built-in XPath 1.0 support, I think you need to use namespaces to select the SVG elements e.g.

```js
var namespaceResolver = function(prefix) {
  if (prefix === 'svg')
    return 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  else
    return null;
}

var path = document.evaluate('//svg:svg/svg:path[@d = "y"]', document, namespaceResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue;


var ancestorButton = document.evaluate('ancestor::button[1]', path, namespaceResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue;

console.log(ancestorButton.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  
  <div>
    <button>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="x" />
      </svg>
    </button>    
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button>                                      <!-- I want this -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="y" />                            <!-- I have this -->
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Or switch to [SaxonJS](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) and XPath 3.1 and use for instance a different default element namespace when looking for SVG and for HTML elements e.g.

```js
const xhtmlNamespace = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';

const svgNamespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

var path = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('//svg/path[@d = "y"]', document, { xpathDefaultNamespace : svgNamespace });


var ancestorButton = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate('ancestor::button[1]', path, { xpathDefaultNamespace : xhtmlNamespace });


console.log(ancestorButton.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.5/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
<div>
  
  <div>
    <button>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="x" />
      </svg>
    </button>    
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button>                                      <!-- I want this -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="y" />                            <!-- I have this -->
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting entangled with [namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

One way to handle this is to change your xpath to

```
//svg[*[local-name()='path'][@d='y']]/parent::*[local-name()='button']
```

and see if it works.

Comment: I think  svg should also also be matched by `*[local-name()='svg']` ?
And I doubt if the button needs te be matched via `local-name()`, since it is html.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I guess it depends on your environment; I tested it using the same demo site as OP and it worked as in the answer, while eliminating `local-name()` from `button` failed. Didn't have the tie to try anything else.

Comment: The demo site shows your XPath and comment are correct.
I still doubt though if this is correct.

Comment: It works on the demo site. But not in the browser: `$x("//svg[*[local-name()='path'][@d='y']]/parent::*[local-name()='button']")` returns an empty array. I'll fiddle with it to see if I can get it to work. Thanks for giving me something to work on!

Comment: @lonix Can you post the link?

Comment: Regrettably it's for an internal app. I'll post back with details if I make progress.